# Dylib not loaded

Tags: xcode, macos, hid, app-bundle

we are creating an Mac OS X app bundle that requires a dylib to be loaded dynamically from the app directory. but when the app is excuted it is unable to find that dylib.

we have even registered the dylib using itool and the dylib is placed in the Framework folder.

Comment: Could you  please give more details on the directory structure, your building process and things like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all i have found this API OneJar(http://wiki.netbeans.org/PackagingADistributableJavaApp) That allows you to create executable jar that includes dynamic libraries in package